# sql query discrepancy

Tags: mysql, sql

while fetching the order from database, the orderNumber is 8 digit code for example: 20178908. But I found some records having alphabets in them: Example F2830P921 and I need to delete those orders.
I used the query:

```
"SELECT {pk} FROM {order} where {ordernumber}=" orderModel.getCode();
```

Can anyone please help me to modify the query to take order number which has alphabets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to *delete* these records, then you may use a delete query with the help of `REGEXP`:

```sql
DELETE
FROM orderTable
WHERE orderNumber REGEXP '[A-Z]';
```

If, on the other hand, you just want to *view* your order data sans these records with alpha order numbers, then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE orderNumber REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: Thank you. But now I have come to know that there are orders with special characters as well like "#$%!*(". I need to include these as well. Can you alter the query accordingly?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74858606/sql-query-to-fetch-orders-from-order-table-where-order-number-have-special-chara